# Child view controller's viewDidLoad is being called before parent view controller's?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In storyboards, I setup ParentViewController to embed ChildViewController. I ran print statements in both of their `viewDidLoad()` methods, and my child view controller's view is loaded before the parent. I do not access the child's view in `prepare(for:)`.

Does anybody know why the child's view is loaded before the parent's? I would think since storyboards/segues automatically call `parentView.addSubview(childView)` that that would mean the parent's view is loaded first so we can call `addSubview`.

Comment: How did you set up the child view controller? You have provided very little information here. It would be helpful to show one code or a storyboard etc...

Comment: I meant the segue/storyboards adds the subview of the child to the parent at some point. It matters because I'm trying to have a better understanding of view controller life cycle's in relation to their children and what could possibly cause the parent view to load last.

I also have code that programmatically sets up and adds a child view controller on ParentViewController in its `viewDidLoad`, and I need to know how/why the parent calls `viewDidLoad` after all the storyboarded child vcs have called theirs first.

Comment: But the content of the "why" question remains unclear. That's just the order of events. It seems perfectly coherent and correct to me. You cannot add a view that is not loaded, so _obviously_ the child must load its view in _order_ for that view to be added to the parent's view. Who cares what order they load in?

Comment: @Fogmeister ChildViewController is an empty ViewController with a print statement in its `viewDidLoad`, it is in storyboards and has an embed segue going from ParentViewController to ChildViewController. It's very barebones, didn't think code mattered much as it would be boilerplate (minus the print in `viewDidLoad`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are forgetting is `loadView()`, the lifecycle method that comes before `viewDidLoad()`. `loadView()` is responsible for view and subview construction and if you print in this method you'll find that the parent's `loadView()` is called before the child's, and that is because the parent's view must be constructed before it can add subviews, like a child's view (you're correct). `loadView()` is also where the parent-child relationship is established (in the parent's `loadView()`) and the parent must get its children to `viewDidLoad()` before getting itself to `viewDidLoad()` because the child's view *is* (in effect) the parent's view. The parent has no view, in some sense, it only displays its children's views. Therefore, the parent must get its children to `viewDidLoad()` before it can claim its own view did load.

Comment: Thanks @bsod, just to clarify, are you saying the parent's `loadView()` is called first, then the child's `loadView()` is called second? If so, wouldn't this mean the parent should trigger `viewDidLoad()` first? I'm confused how it would be the child first if `loadView()` is called on the parent first.

Comment: The parent must load its view before it can add any subview and so the parent's `loadView` will always come before the child's `loadView`. However, the parent-child relationship is also established in `loadView` (in the parent's) and the parent is more interested in getting the child to `viewDidLoad` before getting itself to `viewDidLoad` because the child's view is what the user will see.

Comment: Got it! Can you edit your answer and add your additional explanation (just post the exact comment above in addition to your original answer), I think it helps a lot, and I'll mark yours as the answer. Thanks!